# Google youtube api sample: Where to paste authentication code?

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

Trying to run the sample code here: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/youtube/playlist.js

It opens the browser after `node playlist`, and after allowing all the permissions, displays the screen below.

[image]

Pasting the code back to the console does nothing.
Not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the comments they wrote:

```
  // Open an http server to accept the oauth callback. In this
  // simple example, the only request to our webserver is to
  // /oauth2callback?code=<code>
```

Opened a new window and paste the code in `http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback?code=<code>`. The instruction could be improved imo.